# ServiceStack & NHibernate Integration creating two sessions?

Tags: rest, fluent-nhibernate, servicestack

I'm attempting to follow the blog post here: http://www.philliphaydon.com/2012/06/using-nhibernate-with-servicestack/ though I'm running into an issue with my code.  Basically, I'm setting up the SessionFactory just like Phillip does and my service looks identical to Phillip's.

The issue I'm running into is when attempting to grab data from the DB without stepping through the function--it looks like the session is killed before it can be accessed, and the code then seems to simply just break down:

[image: NHProf ServiceStack Issues]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hw1jW.png

The odd thing is that when I attempt to debug the function by stepping through it, I am returned my result fine and NHProf agrees:

[image: NH Prof ServiceStack Issues2]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfNSi.png

Kind of odd, if anyone had any answer on why this was occurring it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After looking into this more it looks like if I don't dispose the session this issue does not occur.  Clearly this is not the best solution!

Comment: I am interested in this too since I am following the same example.

Comment: I took this example copied it and created my own simple model for a simple select query, I can see in my FindService that the intial result is getting data and mapping correctly to the model but when this block is ran the result comming back to my consumer is null.  return new ProductFindResponse
                {
                    Result = result.TranslateTo&lt;ProductFindResponse.Product&gt;()
                };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What happens if you dispose the session on EndRequest?  That should allow you to not have to worry about disposing your session ever time you make a database call.

I use the following in my web.config to allow me to attach to the Init event within my FluentSessionManager.cs:

```
<httpModules>
        <add name="MyFramework.FluentSessionManager" type="MyFramework.FluentSessionManager" />
</httpModules>
```

Within my FluentSessionManager.cs that lives at namespace MyFramework:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.EndRequest += Application_EndRequest;
    }

public static void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        // Perform the disposing of your session here.  Commit, close, etc....
    }
```

This should allow you to close and dispose your session upon the EndRequest event.  This also prevents you from having memory leaks and zombie connections to your SQL server.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: This appears to have worked!  The one thing I've always been worried about with sessions & web requests is concurrency.  For example, I'm still opening my session within my Get method, and in my end request i'm using NHSessionFactory.GetCurrentSession(), then closing that session.  What happens if two requests happen at the same time and open two separate sessions?  Or what (in the case we only get the current session and reuse it among all requests) if nHibernate closes the session in the middle of another request using it?

Comment: Think about it this way.  Visitor a and visitor b get completely different sessions that are bound to them uniquely.  Also, when you are making a request to the server from your page even if you have 10 concurrent requests at the same time, each request is unique.  Therefore completely different sessions will be used.  You are trying to look at it from an overall standpoint.  That is not how it works.  You need to look at it from a request standpoint.  Just worry about 1 request at a time.  The server sorts out all the concurrent requests.  Hopefully this helps put your mind at ease.

Comment: To fully answer your question about what happens when 2 requests come in concurrently is that they will get a separate session independent of each other.  One request will not influence the other request.

Comment: Thanks!  What was confusing me was the fact that I don't understand ASP.NET too well and was confused by the HttpApplication context parameter if that makes sense.